# Running react native bare project results in error A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I have installed react native through the expo kit and now when I run yarn run android I received that error. I haven't changed anything on the template. I don't know what is happening.? If there are further about feel free to ask. I have also checked the build.gradle of react native reanimated but ,unfortunately , no success has shown up.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\David\Desktop\TheGuruApp\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build.gradle' line: 89

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.      

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\David\Desktop\TheGuruApp\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build.gradle' line: 89

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.      

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
```

Comment: It's not only this lib, I have removed and now the error is in react-native screen

Comment: Facing same issue, any solution.

Answer (score 5):

You have install Android API level 29 and reopen the project... then it will fix itself.

Just go to sdk manager from android studio and install android 10.0(Q) level 29 , show package details google apis intelx86 Atom system image

and restart android studio and open the project it will work...
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtu0d.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your development environment for react native. Use the following link

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Also check the jdk version it should be above or 11.0

Answer (score 0):

The below mentioned code inside `build.gradle` (`node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build.gradle`) is problematic:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        def name = variant.name.capitalize()
        task "jar${name}"(type: Jar, dependsOn: variant.javaCompileProvider.get()) {
            from variant.javaCompileProvider.get().destinationDir
        }
}
```

If this is replaced with the below mentioned code, the said problem is fixed.

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        def name = variant.name.capitalize()
        task "jar${name}"(type: Jar, dependsOn: variant.javaCompile) {
            from variant.javaCompile.destinationDir
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on windows, was the wrong Android SDK path on local.properties file. Needs double backslashes